# How do I turn a form input type="text" into a HREF that sits behind a submit button, using HTML's 5 download attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to do something that in my head seems very simple but for some reason, I can't work it out and I've exhausted google, so hoping someone here can help me out.

I want to create a form input text box, in which I input a link to, for example a CSV file, and it must force the download to disk by pressing the submit button. Seems easy.

Some very simple HTML:

```
<html>
<head><title>FTD</title></head>
<body>
<form name="FTD">
<p><b>Force To Disk CSV Downloader</b></p><br>
<p>Enter your URL in the text field below and hit the Submit button.</p><br>
<input type="text"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Download now">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So what I've tried to do, is use the HTML5 download attribute to complete this task (not in above code as it didn't work). The functionality here is that I will know the link where the CSV or XML is stored beforehand, but I want to make sure it will force to disk download rather than open in my browser, due to the fact that some of these files can well be over a GB in filesize, on which the browser will run out of memory.

Basically, if I throw in http://www.example.com/examplefile.csv  into the text field, pressing submit should grab that input, turn it into an HREF, and use the HTML5 download attribute to force it to download to my hard drive rather than open in my browser.

Example on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download   where I would replace the HREF there and the file would sit behind the image. Instead of using an image, I want the user to be able to input the URL into a text field, and have the submit button force the download of the file on that link, to my HDD.

Is there a simple way to do this, or is using some JavaScript or PHP inevitable here?

I'm not very experienced yet, so apologies if this is a really silly one :-)

Thanks!
Kind regards,

Linkfish

Comment: If your goal is just to download files from URLs that you know, using a command-line `wget` or `curl` command would work better than hacking something together in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger submit form (with your link in form action) through JS, like this:

```js
document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function(){
 document.getElementById('myForm').action = document.getElementById('input_link').value;
 document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
});

//Try with this link:
//https://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv
```

```html
<form id="myForm" method="get" action="">
  <input type="text" id="input_link"/>
  <button type="button" id="download">Download!</button>
</form>
```

So, when user click on button, you replace input link to form action attribute and trigger submit. I hope this help you.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I found it didn't work exactly the way I wanted. I'm still struggling with this. Basically your code does what it's supposed to do, but this only works for CSV files. An XML file, for example, will still open in the browser. 

Basically, I will need the id="input_link" , to contain <a href="input_link" download></a> , so using the HTML5 download attribute, the file will download to my hard disk rather than open in a browser window. I've messed around a bit but can't work out where to place the extra pieces. Can you help me?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

just put your button in a link, and give the href to the link with the attribute download

```
<a href="myfile.pdf" download>
<input type="submit" value="Download now">
</a>
```